# ViewPager wait to finish before all Fragments are done

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a  situation where All of my Fragments of ViewPager are doing DB activity onPause. This piece of code is working fine until I recently implemented sqlcipher. Because of sqlcipher code, my execution is little slow and if I come out of pager and goes back into the pager, I am getting AskcTask errors because, The tasks from previous ViewPager are still trying to update to DB.

Now I want my ViewPager to wait to finish until all of its Fragments are done. Any suggestions please?